# How to generate a sequence of subgraphs using networkx or graph-tool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-tool

How to generate a sequence of subgraphs using networkx?

For example:

I want to generate the following subgraph1

**subgraph1**

`Edges: [(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]`

This graph has a max degree of 3 and a depth/diameter(longest path) of 4

**subgraph2**

`Edges: [(10,11), (10,12), (10,13), (10, 17), (11,25), (12,25), (13,25), (17,14), (14, 20)]`

This graph has a max degree of 4 and a depth/diameter(longest path) of 3

`.....`

I have the following constraints

1) The vertex numbers should not overlap between subgraphs

2) All vertices within a subgraph must have at least one edge and no loops.

3) I want to be able to generate 1000 such subgraphs with a configurable number of degree and diameter

I am fine with using any library like [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) or [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/).

Comment: The documentation here: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html lists all the generators available for networkx.

Comment: couldn't figure out what I need from that documentation which is why I am posting in SO